# Identity authentication for existing asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

Have one Asp.net **mvc** project **without** database. For all of select/insert/update task Need to use some third party api, Seen lots of example on the web, all are used Identity.EntityFramework for  Identity authentication . As have no database how to apply Identity authentication for my project.

Comment: Refer [How to use ASP.NET Identity without a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543193/how-to-use-asp-net-identity-without-a-database) for some options